# Options for functional equivalent to Azure SQL Always Encrypted column encryption

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a requirement to protect PCI data. Dynamic Data Masking is insufficient because Snowflake admins can circumvent the masking to reveal data. We would like something that is functionally equivalent to Azure SQL Always Encrypted where column encryption is secured with a key vault certificate. What options do we have with Snowflake? Do we require a third party solution?

Comment: Have you looked at the Snowflake ENCRYPT function? If it doesn’t meet your requirements then can you explain your requirements in more detail?

Comment: I am looking for an option that Snowflakes admins cannot circumvent. Admins can grant themselves the roles that permit them to unmask the dynamic data masking policies. With Azure SQL Always Encrypted, certificate management is not under the control of the db admins which prevents them accessing data to which they are not authorized.

Comment: Ok - in which case you would need to implement your own encryption/decryption process external to Snowflake (and call it from Snowflake using external functions if that’s a requirement). Unfortunately not something I can help with